# How to yank an entire block in Vim?

Tags: python, vim

Is it possible to yank an entire block of Python code in Vim?

Be it a `def`, `for`, `if`, etc. block...

Comment: "Belongs on superuser.com", maybe? I'm not sure ...

Comment: Don't agree, this is about the use of a software tool in a specific development process (coding Python), see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/which-types-of-programming-related-questions-are-appropriate/12378#12378

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can yank a paragraph with `y}`. This will not yank all the methods if you have a blank line though.

Comment: You can use Ctrl-v and y} to see which lines will be yanked. You can press } as you want to cover your block.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to yank everything except the `{` use `yi{` (or `yi}`).  If you to include the curly braces use `ya{` (or `ya}`).

The `i` and `a` modifiers mean *in* and *all*.

To yank a word no matter where in the word you are: `yiw`

To yank the contents of parentheses: `yi)`; if you want to include them, use `ya(`

You can do the same for `"` or `'` with `yi"`, `ya"` or `yi'` and `ya'`.

Of course, you're not limited to yanking.  You can delete a word with `diw` or change it with `ciw`, etc... etc...

Comment: Great for a C language. I think the question was specific to python though.

Comment: There is also `p` to yank the current paragraph (that is anything separated by blank lines above an below). `yip` yanks the entire paragraph, and `yap` yanks the entire paragraph + the following blank line. This is useful if your cursor is already somewhere inside the paragraph you want to yank.

Comment: Where is this feature in the help document? I look for a long time did not find the corresponding URL.The modifier cannot be found using `help: a`.

Answer (score 9):

The excellent add-on suite [Python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) includes some [key commands](https://github.com/klen/python-mode#default-keys) to navigate classes, methods, and function blocks.

- To yank a method: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (inner method: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>)
- To yank a class: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

There are other handy motions, like moving from function-to-function (<kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>). See the [complete list of keys](https://github.com/klen/python-mode#default-keys) for more.

Answer (score 4):

There's a vim add-on script [python_fn.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30) which has, as one of its functions, a key binding to visually select a block of Python code using `]v`.  You could then yank it with `y` as normal.

Answer (score 4):

I usually just use visual block mode. Shift-V, move, and 'y'ank the highlighted block. There's only so many shortcuts I can keep in memory at once :)

Comment: This is what I usually do too, I don't think it's the best way, but it's easy enough to do with one brain cell :)

Comment: the visual selection is also very useful for indenting/dedenting blocks using > and <

Answer (score 4):

You can combine a search with yank, so if your function ends with `return retval` you can type `y/return retval`

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter visual line selection by pressing 'V'
2. When finished selecting the block pres 'y'
3. Paste it somewhere with 'p' or 'P'

Answer (score 1):

I made a plugin named [spacebox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3997) which does a Visual selection of all lines with the same or more indentation as the current line.

With Python whitespace being the way it is, you could place your cursor on the line below `def` or `if`, and issue the command `:SpaceBox` to select your "block".

Answer (score 1):

[vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) works pretty well. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Just fold the class using za and then use visual mode ( V ) to select the collapsed class. This way you don't have to scroll too much. Then just yank with y. When you are done yanking unfold the class with za again.

Answer (score 0):

1. In .py file, press `Esc`
2. Press `shift V` to enter visual line mode
3. Highlight with up and down arrow keys
4. Press `d` to delete the selected rows
5. Go to the row you would like to place the lines and press `p` to paste lines after a row or press `shift P` to paste before a row

Hope that helps.